# Como mudar a posição dos elementos Ticks no JqPlot?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso saber como mudar a posição dos Ticks (Entidades do Gráfico) para que fiquem na diagonal ao invés da vertical, pois como mostrado na imagem em anexo, os nomes sobrescrevem uns aos outros quando atingem um certo tamanho.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var s1 = [21, 61, 72, 10, 30, 15, 30, 51, 22, 48];
    var ticks = ['Eduardo Nobre da Silva Sousa', 'Eduardo Nobre da Silva Sousa', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo', 'Eduardo'];
    plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
        // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..                 
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: false
        }
    });
    $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataClick',
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#info1').html('series: ' + seriesIndex + ', point: ' + pointIndex + ', data: ' + data);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

[image: grafico]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei a resposta, é bem simples é só adicionar o objeto abaixo e definir o angulo.

```
axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
          angle: -70,
          fontSize: '10pt'
         }
    },
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]